# Set File_Path for to_csv() in Pandas

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

```
funded=r'C:\Users\hill\Desktop\wheels\Leads(1).csv'
funded= read_csv(funded)
funded=DataFrame(funded)
path='C:\Users\hvill\Destop\ '
funded.to_csv(path,'greenl.csv')
```

I want to have a variable that I can set the path in to_csv to. I tried path_or_buf = path. That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to either escape your back slashes or better use a raw string:

```
path='C:\\Users\\hvill\\Destop\\'
```

or better as fewer characters:

```
path=r'C:\Users\hvill\Destop\'
```

I also think you want to do this when saving:

```
funded.to_csv(path+'greenl.csv')
```

To avoid the ambiguity and allow portability of your code you can use this:

```
import os
funded.to_csv(os.path.join(path,r'green1.csv'))
```

this will append your csv name to your destination path correctly

Comment: Just in case is of help to anybody, I construct a path concatenating strings and I wanted to add the r, so the result has been `asada.to_csv(r"" + RESULTS_DIR + "viajes_withDIF_AUX_42.csv", ......`

Answer (score 3):

It may just be the case that you missed the k out of desktop

Answer (score 0):

When [`pandas.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is called with two arguments, the first one means *the file name to use* (including any absolute or relative path). The second one means *the text to use between cells in the output* (CSV stands for "comma-separated values", but many programs that "read CSV files" can use different things besides commas, so Pandas gives the option to use something else).

Therefore, `funded.to_csv(path,'greenl.csv')` does not make any sense. The `path` is a folder name, not a file name, so Pandas cannot open it and write any data. If it could, it would try to use the text `greenl.csv` between every cell in the data (instead of a comma), which is clearly nonsense.

To solve the problem, create the full path and use that as the first argument, for example by using `os.path.join`, or using the `pathlib.Path` class to represent paths.