# Write Pandas Dataframe to CSV with a variable name in pathway

Tags: pandas, operating-system, export-to-csv, sys

I've written a python script that takes in a file and matches some columns in another file.  I would like to write this to a csv with the name "[original file name]_matched".  E.g. I have a bunch of files (xaa, xab, ...) and after running the script on each file I would also have (xaa_matched, xab_matched, etc...)  This is what I've tried based on this solution: [Set File_Path for to_csv() in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872952/set-file-path-for-to-csv-in-pandas)

```
import sys
import os
filename = sys.argv[1]
# some code 
path = r'/Users/mdong/dataScience/movie_representation/fuzzy_match_dir/'
input_file.to_csv(os.path.join(path,'match_' + filename), index = False)
```

However, I get back this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "movie_matching.py", line 29, in <module>
    input_file.to_csv(os.path.join(path,filename), index = False)
  File "/Users/mdong/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1413, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/Users/mdong/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1568, in save
    compression=self.compression)
  File "/Users/mdong/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 382, in _get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, errors='replace')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/mdong/dataScience/movie_representation/fuzzy_match_dir/fuzzy_match_dir/xaa.csv'
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong in order to troubleshoot, any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: The obvious thing to do would be to check your path. Did you do it?

Comment: do you mean checking if the directory exists?  It does not, because fuzzy_match_dir is replicated twice in the pathway, but I don't think I'm using os.path.join correctly, or if this is even the best way to create a variable pathway.

Comment: What is the value of `sys.argv[1]` coming in?

Comment: I'm passing in a csv file from the command line so if I call python3 movie_matching_cahl.py xaa, sys.argv[1] would be xaa.  I'm trying to use it so I can write the output to a file like xaa_matched for every file in the directory.

Comment: The error does not match the code that is shown. There is clearly no [mre] here; voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

I would use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html) in this situation.

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/Path/to/your/folder/')
input_file.to_csv(Path(p, 'match_' + filename + '.csv')), index=False)
```

I would also check that your filename variable is what you expect it to be. Which you can do with Pathlib as well.

```
>>> p = Path('/Path/To/Thing.csv')
>>> p.stem
'Thing'
>>> p.name
'Thing.csv'
```